# Problems with 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

Tags: android

I want to change eclipse to Android studio, but I can't solve a lot of problems:
I use class ActionBarActivity, but have an error and add  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+' 
in Dependences, next problem is

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0-rc1
```

I tryed to fix it: put  'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+' but have error with Theme.AppCompat

I'm Ukrainian and so sorry for my english.  Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+` or `com.android.support:appcompat-v13`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
```

in your build.gradle?

This is what I have without any problems

Comment: If use 20 I can't compile it on Genymotion(nexus 5, 4.2.2, API 19) with this error:  1284-1284/ua.viperhit.contextmenu E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ua.viperhit.contextmenu, PID: 1284
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ua.viperhit.contextmenu/ua.viperhit.contextmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: On Virt. Devise shows message "Unfortunately, Context Menu has stoped"

Comment: There is no .apk file to try( where I can find it?

Comment: enable usb debugging on your phone, plug it in to your computer, and then launch the app in debug mode with android studio.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't do it, because there is no drivers for my Lenovo s820(

Comment: link for my device is unavailable(  https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B3qYFBKKL2hieUhjSFJBOVZwbFk